# Volume of a parallelepiped depending on $\lambda$

Tags: calculus, volume

I've got a relatively simple calculus problem here but it has an unknown variable that I am not sure how to deal with.

> Find the volume of the parallelepiped depending on $\lambda$ with;
>
> $a = [2\lambda,2,2], b=[4,1,\lambda], c=[2,2,\lambda], where\ \lambda$ is an element of >$[-3;1]$
>
> For which $\lambda$ element of $[-3;1]$ is the volume a maximum?

Using the formula for dealing with parallelepipeds;

> $v=|a.(b$x$c)|$

I obtained;

> $V(\lambda)=|2(-\lambda^2-2\lambda+6)|$

Now I am not entirely sure where to go from here and what exactly the answer i'm supposed to show is.

My 2 main questions are;

1. If I factorise the above equation and find two values for $\lambda$, do I just put them back into the equation $(-\lambda^2-2\lambda+6)$ and obtain the volume? If so, which one do I put in?
2. What is the last line asking for? (volume a maximum bit)

I hope I was clear enough in my questioning.

Comment: 1. The two values for $\lambda$ are the two values where $V=0$.  That would be the minimum volume.  Think of a parabola and where it is maximum.

Comment: @Michael Yep thanks! Got the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your work (with a slight correction), $V(\lambda)=|2(-\lambda^2-2\lambda+6)|$.  Thus for each value of $\lambda$ you get a corresponding volume.  The shape of $V$ with respect to $\lambda$ is a parabola opening downward, on the interval in question.  You want to find the value of $\lambda$ that maximizes $V$, and the corresponding maximum value of $V$.

Comment: So I need to differentiate the equation, set $dy/dx$ to 0 and find the maximum? (a quick calculation shows that the maximum is at $\lambda$ = -1) and correspondingly $V = 14$.

So my answers would be $\lambda$ = -1 and $V = 14$?

Comment: @PejmanPoh:  A nit:  when you differentiate the equation, you are finding $frac {dV}{d\lambda}$, not $\frac {dy}{dx}$.  This becomes important if you want to substitute it into other equations.  But your answers are correct.

Comment: Oh yes of course. Was just doing it quickly in my head and typing while reading. Alright thanks a lot for the help :)